Django admin tabularinline similar queries
I'm developing an online store using Django. I have a main class Product
class Product(models.Model)
    our_code = models.CharField('Наш артикул', max_length = 255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField('Наименование',max_length = 255, blank=True, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField('Полное наименование',max_length = 255, blank=True, null=True)
    PRICE_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('manual', 'Ручная установка'),
        ('rrc', 'РРЦ'),
        ('mrc', 'МРЦ'),
    ]


    CURRENCY_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('rub', 'RUB (₽)'),
        ('usd', 'USD ($)'),
        ('eur', 'EUR (€)'),
        ('gbr', 'GBP (£)'),
    ]

    price_type = models.CharField('Тип цены',max_length=10, choices=PRICE_TYPE_CHOICES, default='manual')
    manual_price = models.DecimalField('Ручная цена',max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    rrc_price = models.DecimalField('РРЦ', max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    mrc_price = models.DecimalField('МРЦ', max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True) 
    currency = models.CharField('Валюта',max_length=10, choices=CURRENCY_TYPE_CHOICES, default='rub')
    price_currency = models.DecimalField('Цена в валюте', max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True) 
    text_short = models.TextField('Краткое описание', blank=True, null=True)
    text_full = models.TextField('Полное описание', blank=True, null=True)

Associated with it is the ProductWith class, which stores similar products and is displayed in the Product class in the admin panel
class ProductWith(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='primary_product_with', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Товар')
    product_with = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='product_with_products_with', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Советуем купить')

code admin.py
class ProductWithAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductWith
    fk_name = 'product'
    extra = 0
    raw_id_fields = ('product_with',)
    autocomplete_fields = ('product_with',)

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ProductProviderAdmin, ProductImageAdmin, ProductAnalogAdmin, ProductColorAdmin, ProductWithAdmin,)
    search_fields = ['name', 'our_code']
    autocomplete_fields = ["category", "manufacturer", "provider"]

The problem is that when you open a product in the admin panel that has ProductWith, similar queries occur (exactly as many as there are products)
i tried using select_related and prefetch_related but nothing helps
here is the output of Django toolbar
SELECT ••• FROM main_product WHERE main_product.id IN (22539)
9 similar queries.     1,02
Sel Expl Prof
+
SELECT ••• FROM main_product WHERE main_product.id IN (22569)
9 similar queries.     3,01
Sel Expl Prof
+
SELECT ••• FROM main_product WHERE main_product.id IN (22643)
9 similar queries.     0,00
Sel Expl Prof
+
SELECT ••• FROM main_product WHERE main_product.id IN (22644)
9 similar queries.     0,00
Sel Expl Prof
+
SELECT ••• FROM main_product WHERE main_product.id IN (22801)
9 similar queries.     0,00
Sel Expl Prof
+
SELECT ••• FROM main_product WHERE main_product.id IN (22803)
9 similar queries.     0,00
Sel Expl Prof
+
SELECT ••• FROM main_product WHERE main_product.id IN (23143)
9 similar queries.     1,02
Sel Expl Prof
+
SELECT ••• FROM main_product WHERE main_product.id IN (23144)
9 similar queries.     3,11
Sel Expl Prof
+
SELECT ••• FROM main_product WHERE main_product.id IN (23201)
9 similar queries.

My guess is that the queries are from setting the (initial) choices on the product_with autocomplete field on each of the inline forms. There isn't any way around this; each field needs to query the database separately. This should just be a simple, fast exists() query, though. If the queries are too slow, check whether there is some expensive ordering or annotations happening.
